# jQuery UI Tabs rotate, fx and event: mouseover all together in one

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-tabs

I've looked at all the tutorials I can find, examined the questions on here and read the jQuery UI Tabs source but I still can't figure this out.

My goal is to have a rotating content box, with an fx fade and mouseover effect on the navigation numbers.

You can see the almost working version here:
http://www.chesapeakelifemag.com/index.php/cl_new/index

As you can see the mouseover works and the rotation works but the effects won't show. This is the code I'm working from

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#content_slider").tabs(
          {event: 'mouseover'}).tabs(
          { fx: [{opacity: 'fadeOut', duration: 'slow'},
          {opacity: 'toggle', duration: 'fast'}] }).tabs(
         'rotate', 5000, true);
  });
```

I feel like I'm stringing together a ton of arguments that should all go into one .tabs() function but when I try that the functionallity of mouseover, fx or rotation breaks.

Does anyone have an answer?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#content_slider").tabs({event: 'mouseover', 
        fx: [{opacity: 'fadeOut', duration: '100'}, 
             {opacity: 'toggle', duration: 'fast'}]}).tabs(
        'rotate', 7000, true);
});'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following format:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#content_slider").tabs({
        event: 'mouseover',
        fx: {
            opacity: 'toggle',
            duration: 'slow'
        }
    }).tabs('rotate', 5000, true);
});
```

I use tabs in an application and I added the above fx property and it worked. I'm not certain that your script structures the effects correctly.

Comment: Thanks this got me to the point of getting it working. With the fx you can pass it as an array (fx: [image hiding, image showing]) and I guess I wasn't formatting things correctly when I tried to do it with event: mouseover.